# Dreamweaver CS4 - .flv player preloader

Tags: javascript, video, flv, flash, dreamweaver

Is it possible to show how many % of the video is loaded?
I just need a simple string like: 32% loaded...

(I use non-streaming (progressive loading))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FLV player that is built in, you can pretty much only do what you see, so displaying the % loaded, if not already displayed in the skin itself, is either not supported, or not documented. You can make your own skin http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html or use one of the many other available options http://www.google.com/search?q=flv+player, or try the Widget Browser version (which should be CS4 compatible) of the [HTML5 Video Player Widget](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=2294029), and that player is based on the following http://www.kaltura.org/project/HTML5_Video_Player it is [theme-able](http://www.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/Player_Themable.html). I've not seen a way to show the percentage yet, but perhaps their docs show how to do it.

There is another reference for talking back and forth between Flash and JavaScript, http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html, but you'd need to know what to call, and again, the built in player doesn't appear to be documented well, at least from external interaction, or modifications of the skins themselves.

Comment: "the built in player doesn't appear to be documented well" - thats so real.. thank you for your time Danilo T.T awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not dreamweaver player and it doesn't show %, but this is what I use in my projects http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

It is a pretty cool player.

Comment: thank you for your repsonse - but I still need help for the Dreamweaver player

Comment: As far as I know their player is pretty restricted. I think you can only change the skin.